# why dlsym function only pass the first character，when put a string? C.GoString and C.CString transfer

Tags: c, linux, go, cgo

this is my code, it call the so file.

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>

void cmd_read(const char *c) {
    void (*go)(char*);
    void *h;
    char *error;

    h = dlopen("./cgo_cmd.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!h) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return;
    }

    go = dlsym(h, "ReadFromCMD");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
            fputs(error, stderr);
            exit(1);
    }

    go(c);
    dlclose(h);
```

when the c is "hello world", the output is just "h".

the result should be "hello world".
this is func ReadFromCMD, go code:

```
func ReadFromCMD(path string) {
    fmt.Printf(path)
}
```

- end
  the answer is go string and c string convert. in golang, receive the c string type to *C.char, and handle it by C.GoString, so you can use it now.
  the code like this:

```
//export ReadFromCMD
func ReadFromCMD(path *C.char) {
    p := fmt.Sprintf("%s", C.GoString(path))
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Comment: AFAICT, this is _not_ a `dlsym` issue. Because you're getting _some_ output, it is working and you _are_ calling `ReadFromCMD`. This is a `cgo` or `go` issue. I'm not familiar with `go`, but if it's similar to `printf` in C, I'd say change `fmt.Printf(path)` into `fmt.Printf("%s\n",path)`. If you still have an issue, I'd question what is in `path`. That is, before you call the target function, add (e.g.) `printf("cmd_read: c='%s'\n",c);` in `cmd_read`. Note that `c` is a C string, which is just chars followed by 0. You may need to _convert_ this to a go `string` type before doing `go(c);`

Comment: You're passing a C `char*` into a go `string`, these are very different types. I would have `ReadFromCMD` accept a C string if it is going to be called from C.

Comment: hi,  @Craig Estey,  thank you very much, i solved this question, thans for your thinking, i just feel mess when i try to solve it in a long time. this is my code.[https://go.dev/play/p/YZsT7pnacux](https://go.dev/play/p/YZsT7pnacux)

Comment: @JimB, hi thank u, i solved this question by your thinking![https://go.dev/play/p/YZsT7pnacux](https://go.dev/play/p/YZsT7pnacux)

Comment: Since you found an answer it would be great if you cold post it in an actual answer here for further users to immediately see that this is solved.

Comment: @cafce25, ok, sorry I am fresh man, but I want to be better.

Comment: No worries, just go ahead and add it :D